# iOS UINavigation Controller basics and custom back button

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller

I make my first "serious" iOS app, and have some troubles with the whole UINavigation concept, but all in order. I look answers for my questions but don't find what I want, so here it is.

I want to make menu to a game, it would be look like so:

> 1) It's a RootViewController and it contain some buttons: new game, options, about.
>
> 2) I think it will be another view controller (It must appear when we touch new game button, and we see a menu when we choose game difficulty) the buttons is: easy, medium, hard
>
> 3) The game view controller (I think that this VC won't be the part of UINavigationController).

I have some concepts that I want to embody in this menu.

Here is it: I don't want to use UINavigationController Navigation bar, I won't use standard slide animation for UINavCon, I want to make my buttons "move to transparency" and come back with another menu from paragraph 2 mentioned above, it's not necessarily to change background  or something else except menu items. 
I want to use custom back button, and want to add it to the position I want and not to Navigation Bar.

I have some ideas about animation of menu items.

I don't know this:

It is better to use UINavigationController for my purposes or it's better to use normal ViewController?

If I make a UINavigationController can I see it's "child VCs (I mean not a root VC)" in my storyboard or it will be programmatically created thing and I must make it UI in code? If i must do this programmatically, could I make a segue from UINavigationController from storyboard, or I must do this from code too?

Could I make a UIButton, for example, and assign it functions from a normal UINavigationController back button from Navigation Bar?

Some questions might be dumb, but hope you won't judge me hard.

Comment: If you use segues and storyboards, you can choose custom animation, and you could do this with `[UIView animate:]` by simply changing the transparency.

Comment: @glenwayguy do you mean, that I can avoid UINavigationController and use the segues only?

Comment: No, use a UINavigationController. To move to the next view controller, connect the button to a segue to the next screen. If you click on the segue and look in its attributes, under one tab you should be able to select custom animation, or something to that extent.

Comment: @glenwayguy no, on the attribute inspector I only able to change segue type and add a segue identifier. I think I could make this animation in code in `performSegue` for fade out from "root controller" and fade in in `viewDidLoad` from "second controller"

Comment: click on "style" and change it from push to custom

Comment: Oh, the segue class input has appear, I must make a class of segue? when I can read about it?

Comment: Yes, you make a custom segue class with the animation. try: http://joris.kluivers.nl/blog/2013/01/15/custom-view-controller-transitions-using-uistoryboardsegues/ and http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/CreatingCustomSegues/CreatingCustomSegues.html and http://www.cmumobileapps.com/2011/11/04/a-short-tutorial-on-custom-segues/

Comment: Did this work for you? If it di, I'll add it as an answer.

Comment: @glenwayguy It might be good for me, but I want to get answer for others my questions here, thanks for your help glen, if nobody answer me about my questions, of course I accept your help as a answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, I'll do my best:
For custom animations, see

Yes, you make a custom segue class with the animation. try: joris.kluivers.nl/blog/2013/01/15/… and developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/… and cmumobileapps.com/2011/11/04/a-short-tutorial-on-custom-segues

Yes, i think a view controller is your best bet. But by the way, even if you use a navigation controller, you still use normal view controllers. A UINavigationController holds different UIViews, which go forward and backward on the navigation stack. Also, you will need to look up what you need to do to hide the navigation controller.

You can see the child view controllers in a storyboard if you create them their, but not if they are created programmatically, unless you just have the view in their.
`[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES]` will "press the back button" programmatically, so just link the custom back button to a method that calls this.

If that doesn't cover all of your questions, just comment and I'll answer any more :)